# What is "Label Not define" in my VBA code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the VBA code in MS Access

```
Private Sub ToolingNoID_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo ToolingNoID_AfterUpdate_Err

Dim ToolingNoID As String
ToolingNoID = InputBox("Please enter Tooling No", "Enter Tooling No")

If (IsNull(ToolingNoID)) Then
    Exit Sub
    Beep
    MsgBox "Please enter the tooling number.", vbOKOnly, ""
    DoCmd.CancelEvent
End If

End Sub
```

The offence line is

```
Private Sub ToolingNoID_AfterUpdate()
```

I really have no idea which part of my code should be changed to fufill the above condition. Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line isn't the `Sub` declaration, it's this line:

> ```
> On Error GoTo ToolingNoID_AfterUpdate_Err
> ```

There is no `ToolingNoID_AfterUpdate_Err` label in your procedure. Remove the `On Error` statement, or add an error-handling subroutine at the end of the procedure:

```
    Exit Sub
ToolingNoID_AfterUpdate_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, "Unexpected Error", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

In VBA a "line label" is defined by an identifier followed by a colon, at the beginning of a line of code (and ideally, sitting on its own line):

```
LineLabel:
```

"Label not defined" is the compile error you get when an instruction is referring to a label that doesn't exist in that scope.